# access elements of the list of tuples with variable length and save the output in the same format

Tags: python, linux, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples like below

```
a=[(40, 41, 42, 43), (44, 45, 46, 47, 48), (109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114)]
```

Each number represents the ID of a chord. Each tuple represent a part which can have variable number of chords.

I want to apply a loop in such a way that I can access each ID of a chord for each part. In the end I have to apply another function to get the length of each chord based on the id and want to save it too in the same fashion.
e.g.

```
b=[(1.2, 1.4, 1.4, 4.3), (4.4, 1.45, 2.6, 2.7, 2.4), (1.9, 1.1, 1.8, 1.2,13, 1)]
```

How can I apply such a loop with variable counter for each tuple?

What I tried is

```
i= len(a)
j=len(i)
 for k in range(i):
  for l in range(j):
   c =a[k][l]
   length= getLength(c) # function to get length for chord ID c
   b[k][l]= length
```

that getLength function can replaced with any number in the example

Any suggestions?

Comment: `len(i)` doesn't make sense because `i` is an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[tuple(getLength(i) for i in tup) for tup in a]
```

Basically you loop over each "part", which is in fact a tuple through the fragment of code `for tup in a`. For each of these "part" you want you apply the function you want - here `getLength` - to each chord. Basically what `getLength(i) for i in tup` does. And you want a tuple as output ... so just wrap this in the `tuple` function.

---

The list comprehension can be expanded to (but not recommended):

```
b = []
for tup in a:
    chord_length = []
    for id in tup:
        chord_length.append(getlength(id)
    b.append(tuple(chord_length))
```

Comment: Bravo. One liner is efficient but can you break it down for more clarity for beginners like me?